# Изображение в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

Как мне передать картинку через массив? 
Имеется массив 
Const LocalStorage = [
{
Id: 1,
Name: "one"
…
}
…
]

Мне надо добавить в него картинку, которая хранится в папке images

То,что я сейчас делаю, это тихий ужас=> я через map() создаю элементы и к каждому приставляю класс{item.bg-image}...

Comment: добавление строки с путем до изображения не может решить вашу проблему?  сonst IMAGE_STORE = [ { Id: 1, name: "one", slug: '/images/image1.svg' } … ]

Comment: решило. спасибо большое